# Material-UI - alternative of withWidth() for class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-components

The documentation says:

> This higher-order component will be deprecated for the useMediaQuery hook.

I have a class component which means can't use **useMediaQuery hook**.

example code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-0kz88

What is the alternative then?

Comment: I would recommend converting your class to a function component. For most classes, that is very straightforward.